# Data dump posts.xml

Tags: support, data-dump

Approximately how many posts are there in file *posts.xml* in the January 2011 data dump?

I was trying to open my XML in a text editor, but it crashes as the size is enormous.

Comment: How to get the posts.xml?

Comment: download it http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/

Answer (score 1):

[SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) has been updated more recently than that, but depending on how approximately you need it, you can just [run a query there](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/11513/) -- it's at 4830431 right now